# Building cartograms using Web GIS?

Tags: data, visualisation, web-gis, cartogram

I would like to build a cartogram map using Web GIS.

I have a basemap and a set of raw data in excel.

I wondered what are the steps to build up a cartogram map using Web GIS?

**Note**: Originally this Question solicited Answers for both Web GIS and ArcGIS for Desktop.  A new Question has been asked focussed on ArcGIS for Desktop ([Creating contiguous pixel based cartogram using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102208/creating-contiguous-pixel-based-cartogram-using-arcgis-for-desktop)) and so this one has now been focussed on Web GIS (which itself is still quite broad).

Comment: Last year I experimented with cartograms as well. For the cartograms I used a tool called [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/).

Answer (score 4):

A few years ago, I too became curious about how to make cartograms. The best tool I could find at the time was a standalone program called Cartogram Generator *(deprecated link removed)* by [Frank Hardisty](http://www.personal.psu.edu/fah109/index.html). It generates a new shapefile from your basemap, distorted according to the attributes you select.

> The above is described at [this
>   blog](http://indiemaps.com/blog/2008/03/free-cartograms/) as being a
>   java implimentation of the Gastner-Newman diffusion-based contiguous
>   cartogram algorithm. An alternative link to information/software can
>   be found on [Gastner's
>   page](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~mgastner/cartogram/cartogram.html).

I also posted sample images and some other cartogram-related links and thoughts [on my blog](http://anoved.net/2008/10/cartograms/).

I don't know what solutions are available to build cartograms within ArcGIS itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Esri Cartography blog from 2009, you will find an article titled "[Exploring Data Using Cartograms within ArcGIS Desktop](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/gisedcom/2009/10/16/exploring-data-using-cartograms-within-arcgis-desktop/)", and link to the [Cartogram Geoprocessing Tool version 2](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15638), which will supposedly (I have not tried it) will allow you to create cartograms from ArcGIS.

Here, another user has described [How To Make Area Cartogram Maps in ArcGIS](http://www.gislounge.com/how-to-make-area-cartogram-maps-in-arcgis/).

Comment: I did not realize that mods could not move Answers so I have made a Comment on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102208/creating-contiguous-pixel-based-cartogram-using-arcgis-for-desktop to look here for an Answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but D3 has supported continuous area cartogram creation through an external library for a few years now. Check the [interactive example](http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/#popchange/2010). Note that it expects the map to be in TopoJSON format, not a shapefile.

On the main page there are also examples of Demerse and Dorling cartograms.