# Creating contiguous pixel based cartogram using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartogram

There are several types of cartograms out in the world, but I feel the best one are the continuous cartograms made with separate pixels. I recently made one on paper and then transcribed it to excel by filling in each cell with different colors. This was time consuming and disheartening.  Is there a straightforward way of doing a similar cartogram in ArcGIS?

Examples
[image: Credit: improving-visualisation.org]
[image: Credit: Reuters electoral college map]

Comment: I hope to find a solution for this specific type of cartogram. The one referenced as a duplicate question is asking about general cartograms and most of the answers have links that are broken.

Comment: Only one link at the referenced question was broken for me. I edited the post to provide an alternate. However you are correct, that does not address the specific of your comment/question - pixel based. I'll edit your question title to provide this specificity and @Mapperz may reopen it at that point.

Comment: @PolyGeo But what I'm saying is that answer *isn't* valid here, because it only goes to methods for general cartograms, not pixel based ones as this asker seeks.

Comment: @ChrisW The point you make is valid - I'll forgo suggesting more changes on this one but I think the main gardening to be done on the original Question was to separate the Web GIS question from the ArcGIS for Desktop question.  I think the Answer to the latter fits better here but far from perfectly.

Comment: If anyone is looking for methods for general cartograms there is an [**Answer**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43584/building-cartograms-using-web-gis/62622#62622) on another Question that may be useful.

Comment: Joseph - having not actually done the operation, is there any reason you can't use one of the tools supplied in the answers here and at the other question, then do a vector to raster conversion on the results? Presumably by setting the right cell size you could get the pixel 'resolution' you want, though depending on the amount of distortion introduced and cell size selected I'm not sure how well small/thin areas would survive the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The links in the suggested duplicate are depreciated so, this is worth addressing again.

I like [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/) for generating cartograms. It is free, implements a robust algorithm, easy to use and operates on shapefiles.